# Use Angular tags inside google chrome devtool panel

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I didn't manage to make angular work in a new devtool panel, which I added through my chrome extension.

There are no errors, but the angular tags are not parsed at all.

My manifest look like that:

```
{
 "name": "LogTool",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
 "devtools_page": "devtools.html",

 "permissions": [
 "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/",
 "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/",
 "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
 ]
}
```

devtools.html is an empty html which only loads a JS file which inject the panel with the following code:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("LogTool", "/icon.png", "/panel.html",
function(extensionPanel) {
    var runOnce = false;
    extensionPanel.onShown.addListener(function(panelWindow) {
        if (runOnce) return;
        runOnce = true;
        // Do something, eg appending the text "Hello!" to the devtools panel
        //panelWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello!'));
    });
});
```

panel.html is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Logs</title>

    <!-- Angular files -->
    <script    src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.js'></script>

    <!-- Angular bootstrap files -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-    bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-    bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'     href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css' />

    <!-- Internal files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="panel.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-csp="">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ b }}</td>
                <td>{{ b }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is panel.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.a = 1;
    $scope.b = 2;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add remote code just like that due to [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) restrictions. Host permissions you included do not help.

You have two options:

1. Much easier to bundle the resources with your extension: it will make for a faster load time and ensure it works offline. Just add js and css to the extension and refer to them by relative paths.
2. [Relax the CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script). You need to add a manifest key with the new CSP. Note that this will only work on HTTPS domains.