# Javascript external script for Chrome Extension not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension but my it doesn't seem to be able to execute any Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#overlay").hide();
});
```

In this example I'm trying to hide a div with id "overlay" but it doesn't seem to be working. Stored in an external file (popup.js)

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "background": {
     "scripts": [
         "js/background.js"
           ]
    },
    "icons": { "16": "android-16.png",
           "48": "android-48.png",
           "128": "android-128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon" : "android-128.png",
        "default_title": "",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "background", "unlimitedStorage", "tabs"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "index.html","js/popup.js"
    ]
}
```

HTML links situated before body closing tags:

```
<script src="js/background.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, js files are all stored in a folder within the directory called "js"

Comment: Download jQuery and load it like you are loading your scripts.

Comment: Answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29678547/934239 Can't choose as duplicate as it's not upvoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Angular tags inside google chrome devtool panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670938/use-angular-tags-inside-google-chrome-devtool-panel)

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Xan mentioned due to the [CSP will block the script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading) the best way to avoid this and do it work is downloading jquery.js and make it part of your extension.

Comment: Hey, @Xan could you be more specific? neither downloading jquery.js and adding it to the extension doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, the first part. Adding permissions won't help, [CSP will block the script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading). There is a way around that, but as is your answer is half-incorrect. And it was fully incorrect before your edit.

Comment: Thanks @Xan I fixed it, but I think this question can be marked as duplicate as you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75590/discussion-between-nramirez-and-xan).