# Content JavaScript Not Executing in Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension has a Content Script that adds a DIV with a button. The OnClick JS function defined for the button, however, never executes (defined in the same Content Script), so the button does nothing. Why is that?

**contentscript.js**

```
var msg = "Click this button <button onclick='test()'>Test</button>";

var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
div.id = 'testDiv';
document.body.appendChild( div );
document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML = msg;

function test()
{
    alert('in test()');  // Never gets here
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "css": ["contentstyle.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.11.2.min.js", "contentscript.js"]
```

Comment: I not really sure that this would work but try to add the even with javascript to the button
document.getElementById('textBtn').addEventListener('click', test);
If this not work then is because of the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: If what I told you doesn't work then this question is a duplication of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670938/use-angular-tags-inside-google-chrome-devtool-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the official docs regarding policies. Inline javascript is strictly prohibited. The docs explain how to do it. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy